# Google BigQuery: performance(detail)

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to know the performance of google-bigquery.
For example, service time, MTTR (Mean Time To Repair), Disaster Recovery .. etc.
Please tell me URL that can be used for reference.

p.s.

Thank you for your comments.
I know the BigQuery is a fully managed service. However , my boss does not have more information about its performance . **For that I use the BigQuery , my boss will need to know about performance .** I must convince him . Information of detail(MTTR,Disaster Recovery,etc.) is required in order that I convince him . On the basis of the above, please let me know if there is a URL that would be helpful .

(I made ​​sure the [homepage](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sla) . However , detailed information could not be found .)

Comment: As a fully managed service, you don't need to worry about any of that. There's no service time, MTTR (Mean Time To Repair), Disaster Recovery to care of. Google engineers will be taking care of BigQuery running smoothly so you don't need to.

Answer (score 2):

As Felipe has already commented, BigQuery is a **fully** managed service so you do not need to worry about things like that.

A good place to start would be looking at the [homepage](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/what-is-bigquery) of BigQuery to understand what it is/isn't, [my blog](http://blog.shinetech.com/2014/01/18/reeling-in-big-data-using-googles-bigquery/) (shameless plug :)), and finally check out this [great presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kKBnFsNWwYM) from Jordan.